# Cyclic class initialization

Tags: java, class, static, initialization, loading

In java a class is loaded just before an object of the class is created.And a class is loaded only once during the entire duration of the program.
When this happens , statics are initialized and static blocks are executed.
This can be cyclic ; before a class is fully initialized , I created an object of the class in the class iteself.
For eg:

```
public class MyTestClass{

public static MyTestClass myTest= new MyTestClass();

}  


public class Beginner{

public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println(MyTestClass.myTest==null);
}
}
```

When I call MyTestClass.myTest in the main() for the very first time ; MyTestClass will be in the process of loading and I try to create an object of MyTestClass while it's being loaded ; should that not create a cyclic class loading and this can be infinite?
How does this get handled in java?

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please post real code with your question.

Comment: Do you mean `public class Beginner {` instead of `public void Beginner {`?

Comment: i think he mean it that way :-)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of events is like this:

1. The class is loaded and validated, all static memebers are set to null or 0
2. The static initializers and blocks of the class are executed (in lexical order)
3. The code that needed the class proceeds

The execution of initializers in your case includes

```
public static MyTestClass myTest= new MyTestClass();
```

That means the code in the `main` will see `MyTestClass.myTest` that is not null.

The only time you'll see `MyTestClass.myTest` that is null is in the constructor of the the `MyTestClass` instance that is created in the static initializer.